# Google Maps API not letting go of the mouse click

Tags: api, google-maps, onclick

I'm using the Google maps API to place a map onto a web page, just like millions of other sites have done.

However, once I click on the map (and let go), the map then acts if the mouse button is still being held and drags the map all over the page. The only way to get free of this drag action is to hit F5 and reload the page.

I've spent several hours scouring Google to find a remedy to this but can't find any mention of this issue from anyone else.

The problem can be seen at the bottom of the following page:
http://www.ef-deutschland.de/master/lt2010/default.aspx

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vagely remember encoutering something similar a while back, I think it was caused by having an overlay somewhere on the map that wasn't supposed to be there.

Also try simplifying the code, put the map on its own page (without all the other jQuery stuff going on), and remove all parts of your code one by one until you can isolate the problem...

Comment: Thanks Wim. I suspected an overlay was being placed by some other piece of jQuery.

I did just as you suggested with a clean page and worked back towards including the other markup and script includes that the original page has and found that it was GreyBox.js that was causing the issue.

I have a second page which had the same issue and on this page I found it to be Thickbox.js which was causing the problem.

In the latter case I was able to to change all instances of '$' to 'jQuery' and the conflict disappeared.